# I get argument not specified for parameters 'sender' and 'e'?

Tags: vb.net

I use `Call.ProgressUpdate()` to call:

```
Public Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}% completed", e.ProgressPercentage)
    Call Main2()
End Sub
```

But I get the errors:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Public Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)'.

and

> Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Public Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you invoke `Call.ProgressUpdate()`, you need to pass it two arguments.

Comment: @jdigital If I use `Call ProgressUpdate(sender, e)` I get errors that 'sender and 'e' are not declared

Comment: Please don't use `Call` in VB.NET unless it's meaningful. Normal method calls should just be `Main2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very clear why you are calling this method directly, it is supposed to be an event handler.  You'll need to pass the arguments it needs, but that isn't going to work because you cannot create an instance of the DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs class, its constructor is not accessible.  You'll need to break this up into two separate methods, like this:

```
Private Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ShowProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowProgress(percentage As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}% completed", percentage)
End Sub
```

Now you can simply call ShowProgress(0) instead.