# Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Protected Sub TextBox1(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'

Tags: webforms

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub TextBox1(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim userid As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim params(1) As OleDbParameter
        params(0) = New OleDbParameter("uid", TextBox1.Text)
        params(1) = New OleDbParameter("up", TextBox2.Text)
        Dim sql = "select * from user where userid=@uid and userpassword=@up"
        Dim ds As DataSet = AccessHelper.ExecuteDataSet(sql, params)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Session("userid") = TextBox1.Text

        Else
            Dim paramst(1) As OleDbParameter
            paramst(0) = New OleDbParameter("tid", TextBox1.Text)
            paramst(1) = New OleDbParameter("tp", TextBox2.Text)
            Dim sqlt = "select * from teacher where teacherid=@tid and userpassword=@tp"
            Dim dst As DataSet = AccessHelper.ExecuteDataSet(sqlt, paramst)
            If dst.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
                Session("teacherid") = TextBox1.Text
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can't really figure out why I get the errors (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewL9u.png)

No idea what I'm doing really but it's a check to see if the login exists. Beforehand it was saying that textbox1/2 wasn't declared but now it's switched to this; either way it doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

Comment: try this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903576/i-get-argument-not-specified-for-parameters-sender-and-e

Comment: How would I use that? Not really sure how to pick that apart and implement it

Comment: Please add the markup from the file _default.aspx.vb_ (at least the declaration of the TextBox)

Comment: Steve - I posted all of default.aspx.vb, I presume I'm missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Ashish - how do I look at the designer.vb file?

Comment: Looking at the error image attached, i suggest that the 11th error(Textbox1 is Already Declared) is the reason for this. Check your aspx file and remove if there are any multiple declarations of Textbox1.

Comment: Sorry, it is the design aspx file. Please check the declarations in aspx where textbox1 is placed.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0G3CsNJ.png That's what I'm looking at.